# Git Remote Operations (Fetch/Pull/Push) not working on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

I am unable to push/pull/fetch from Git in VS2022. Getting below error:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(c:/program files/microsoft visual studio/2022/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\\git-askpass.exe): No such file or directory
git@****: Permission denied (publickey).
Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
Could not read from remote repository.
```

I can't find the `git-askpass.exe` in the path mentioned.

I am able to push/pull/fetch from Git CMD though. It asks for the ssh passphrase and connects successfully. Only in Visual Studio it is not working.

VS2022 version is 17.1.2

Are there any extra configurations to do in Visual Studio to make Git work successfully?

Comment: Issue got resolved . But i havent made any changes. Dunno how it resolved. Now i am getting prompt for entering the passphrase when performing Git operations in VS2022.

Comment: `git-askpass.exe` is still missing from the mentioned path. but Vs2022 now triggers the prompt for entering passphrase with no errors.. It is frustrating to not know the cause of the initial issue and the solution to it